# How to print id of a name clicked which is in the menu in ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am very much new to ionic and angular

i have an ion-menu which gets data from  `<ion-router-outlet id="mainContent"></ion-router-outlet>` which is in app.component.html .I get data for this menu from the app.component.html 
This is in attendance.page.html
Using this as the menu

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button expand="block" routerLink="/" routerDirection="backward">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <!--Code for menu starts from  here-->
      <ion-menu menu="admin" menuId="first" content-id="mainContent">
          <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
      </ion-menu>

    <ion-title>
      Attendance
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

My first problem

i)How to add icon an icon or small button to this menu on top right corner.this is swipable from the left.How to change code such that it loads the menu on clicking the small icon added now.

Here is the picture of app...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9wz1.jpg

My second problem...

I can output the id when clicking on an name in the menu list as the router outlet is running the code of app.component.ts.I have written this code in app.component.ts to store in a local storage in ionic.This localstorge data can be loaded console on clicking the name menus.But how to reflect that change in the attendance page .This means i should be able to print data on attendance page when the menu is closed.

function to store in local storage

```
 storedata(data){
    console.log(data.id+"This is my global id");

    this.storage.set('id',data.id);
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.storage.get('id').then((val)=>{

        console.log(val+"Testing..................");
      }); // Now the "this" still references the component
   }, 1000);


  }
```

I am using ionic 4

My main aim is to pass the id globally to all pages .For that i have used localstorage.But i need to get the data of localstorge when the name in menu is clicked which is linked to the attendance page from app page using router-outler
Some of my friends suggested to use **ionWillClose** but i am confused on how to use that.Basically i wish to trigger an user-defined-function on ion-menu change

Comment: Can any one give me an example for menuCtrl.toggle() promise usage

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate more on your first problem as to what exactly you want to achieve. More screenshots could help understand the issue.

For your second problem:

1. Not sure if the requirement is to use local storage. But if your only goal is to use the variable globally, use can create a service and keep the variable there and use it.
2. ionWillClose is Emitted when the menu is about to be closed. This is how you can use that in your code.

   ```
   <ion-menu menu="admin" (ionWillClose)="closeFunc()" menuId="first" content-id="mainContent">
        <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
   </ion-menu>
   ```
3. Example for using menuCtrl.toggle()

   ```
   import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

   constructor(private menuCtrl: MenuController) {}

   ngOnInit() {                     // any function you want to access the menuCtrl
       this.menuCtrl.toggle();      // If menu is open, it will try to close, otherwise it will try to open it.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think `sessionStorage` is better than localStorage as it stores the data for entire session. You can store the data as

```
sessionStorage.setItem('id', 'value'); //You can store multiple variables by changing the id
```

You can then retrieve this in any component as:

```
var iD = sessionStorage.getItem('id'); //returns value
```